# Spawn another process and not wait for it

Tags: java, process, exec, processbuilder

I have 2 java processes. I want to start one of the processes from the other process via `ProcessBuilder`.
My problem is that I only want to start the other process. I don't want to wait for any results or output of it.
I.e. after starting the second process the 2 processes will run independently.
How can I do this? By not calling `waitFor` on `ProcessBuilder`? By not consuming the `OutputStreams`?

**Note:** The second process does not produce output and runs "forever". Actually both are long-running processes

Comment: Use threads. That is, start second process in a new thread.

Comment: You have to consume the output, some process will not exit until there output buffers have been read, but you could simply read the stream and ignore it's results.  But the basic answer is use a `Thread`

Comment: What if the second process does not produce any output and runs forever?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the documentation, are you using waitFor method of process class, if yes. Then I guess you need not do it.

Taken from [Process Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

```
**waitFor**

public abstract int waitFor()
                 throws InterruptedException

causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.

Returns:
    the exit value of the process. By convention, 0 indicates normal termination. 
Throws:
    InterruptedException - if the current thread is interrupted by another thread while it is waiting, then the wait is ended and an InterruptedException is thrown.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your process with ProcessBuilder in a separate thread, read stdout and stderr in that thread and ignore them, let the thread exit when the process finished

Comment: What if the second process does not produce any output and runs forever?

Comment: Then the whole app will run forever unless you stop it with System.exit or you stop the second process with Process.destroy

Comment: But what I need is the first and second process to run **independently** and not have a thread in the first process "bind"/"reserved" for the second process